# How to show label styles in map legend?

Tags: qgis, style, legend, qgis-print-layouts

In a QGIS map legend, what methods can be used to show examples of a feature's label, in addition to its symbol?

For example, a single point symbol might be used to show all cities, but the label style may be varied in size, color, typeface (bold, italic, underline etc.) or type case (upper or lower case), in order to show different population, municipal class, and so on. These differences should be indicated in the legend, normally by displaying an examplar label for each different classification, or possibly by varying the style of the item text itself in the legend.